# multiple login page in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have an mvc 4 application, where I have to define multiple login pages, one for each role type user.
  Is there any way to do this? trying to configure multiple login pages inside the location tag in web. config gives me errors.
  thanks,
    luca

Comment: Please provide more information. How do you know what role a user has before they have logged in? If the same user has two roles, what would they do?

Comment: We have a two links to login pages, customers and employees. The role is not known before the login. The user choose the login page and try to login in the site.

Comment: So what would happen if an employee logs in from the customers login page? Which login page would someone be redirected to if their session times out? (Remember you just said you don't know the person's role if they haven't logged in, so you don't know whether to send them to the client page or the employee page.)

Comment: can be redirect to home page, this is not so important in this case.

Comment: Then what is important? Why do you need two different login pages?

Answer (score 1):

One way is just to create different login controllers for each role type. To make it possible for people to access two different login pages while they are not logged in, you can open up those locations in web.config:

```
  <location path="Employee/Login">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Customer/Login">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

You say that when people get logged out they can be redirected to the home page. To do this, in the forms authentication portion of web.config, set `loginUrl` to your home page.

If your login logic is mostly the same, but you want to present a different view, you could reuse the same controller, but have a route value that specifies which mode you're in and switch between Views depending on which value is provided.